# A doubt in the proof of Prop. 1.10 of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a doubt in the proof of Proposition 1.10 of Hartshorne's book Algebraic Geometry, which states that if $Y$ is a quasi-affine variety, then its dimension is the dimension of its closure.

In this proof the author picks a maximal chain $Z_0 \subset Z_1 \subset \dots \subset Z_n$ of irreducible closed subsets of $Y$, and states that then also the "closure" chain $\overline{Z_0} \subset \overline{Z_1} \subset \dots \subset \overline{Z_n}$ of irreducible closed subsets of $\overline{Y}$ is maximal, referring to the fact that an open non-empty subset of an irreducible set is irreducible and dense.
I tried to prove it by contradiction: if the closure chain were not maximal, then there would exist an index $i\in \{0,\dots,n-1\}$ and another irreducible closed subset $W$ of $\overline{Y}$ (which is then closed in all the affine $n$-space) such that $\overline{Z_i} \subset W \subset \overline{Z_{i+1}}$, or $W$ would satisfy $\overline{Z_n} \subset W$. Then my idea was to look at the intersection of these sets with the quasi-affine variety $Y$. But since $Y$ is quasi-affine, $Y=U\cap X$ with $U$ open in the Zariski topology of the affine $n$-space, and $X$ an affine variety, i.e. an irreducible Zariski-closed set. So I have that $Y\cap W=U\cap (X\cap W)$ which is an open subset of the closed set $W\cap X$. But now how can I use the above fact, since I don't know if the set $W\cap X$ is irreducible? Is the intersection of irreducible sets always irreducible?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Dear Diogenes, dare I ask if you are Indian?

Comment: Dear Georges, no... I am European.

Comment: Dear Diogenes: thanks for answering my indiscreet question. I am passionately  interested in linguistics and I have noticed that Indians sometimes use "doubt" where Americans (and other English speaking populations) would use "question". But of course the American  sense of "doubt" makes perfect sense in your question ...

Comment: @ Georges: That's why you asked that question! I was wondering whether the reason was that my written English is awful (it is understood that I am not saying that Indians speak English worse than Europeans, in general!) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact that $Y\cap W$ is open in the irreducible set $W$ to conclude that $Y\cap W$ is an irreducible topological space. It is also closed in $Y$ since $W$ is closed in $X$, so this completes your proof by contradiction.

Comment: I don't see that $Y\cap W$ is open in $W$. I only see that $Y\cap W=U\cap (W\cap X)$ is open in $W\cap X$.

Comment: @Diogenes $W\subseteq\bar Y\subseteq X$ since $X$ is necessarily a closed set in the ambient space. This means $Y\cap W=U\cap(W\cap X)=U\cap W$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so by taking intersections with $Y$ I obtain a chain of irreducible closed subsets of $Y$ which then must be strict otherwise from the density of the opens I'll obtain equality in the closure chain. Is it right? But now I have another doubt: to construct the closure chain we take closures wrt the whole affine space, while to use density we take closures relative to the subspace topologies of the different irreducible subsets, so perhaps the previous reasoning is not right, because we have to take the closures wrt the same subspace to deduce equality...

Comment: The closure of $Y\cap W$ is $W$ respect to both the subspace topology on $W$ and to the topology on affine space since $W$ is closed in affine space itself.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking that perhaps it holds in general that if I take two closed subsets $C_1$ and $C_2$ of a topological space $X$, with $C_1\subseteq C_2$, then if $Y\subseteq C_1$ we have that the closure of $Y$ in $C_1$ is the same as the closure of $Y$ in $C_2$, so this would answer to my previous doubt. Is it correct or not?

Comment: @Diogenes It is correct. Note that the closure of $Y$ with respect to $X$ is contained in $C_1$. A fortiori it is the smallest closed set containing $Y$ in either $C_1$ or $C_2$.

Comment: Ok, I think it's all clear now. Thanks a lot for the help Karl and Kevin! It's incredible to see how many issues arise from a single line of this awfully dense book by Hartshorne. I think I have to live many lives before understanding only the first chapter, at this slow pace...